# How to pass master report data source to subreport (JasperReports)?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I am trying to generate a JasperReport PDF with subreports but I can't access the JRBeanCollectionDataSource (coming from a List) passed as parameter to the main report. Or rather, I just get a blank subreport. I expect to be looping of some sort since I am passing a JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

This is my current code:

Java code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/generate-contract", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity < byte[] > report(
    @RequestBody Contract contract) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    // add params to the MASTER REPORT
    params.put("farmName", contract.getFarmName());
    params.put("farmLogo", contract.getFarmLogo());

    // create a JRBeanCollectionDataSource of the List<Signatory> list
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource signatoriesListSubreportDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(contract.getSignatoriesList());

    // add it as parameters to be read by the master report
    params.put("signatoriesListSubreportDataSource", signatoriesListSubreportDataSource);

    byte[] bytes = reportService.generatePDFReport("my-master-report", params);

    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8")
        .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + contract.getFarmName() + ".pdf\"")
        .body(bytes);
}
```

I am calling a .generatePDF() method where it actually compiles the master report and the subreport as well. I don't know if this is accurate though

```
@Override
    public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params) {
        return generatePDFReport(inputFileName, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
    } // this is where it first goes through

@Override
public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName,
    Map <String, Object> params,
    JRDataSource dataSource) { // then proceeds to this method, creating a blank dataSource

    byte[] bytes = null;
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        // Check if a compiled report exists
        if (storageService.jasperFileExists(inputFileName)) {
            jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                .loadObject(storageService.loadJasperFile(inputFileName));
        }

        String mySignatoriesSubReportFileName = "my-subreport-file-name-here";

        // Compile report from source and save
        String jrxml = storageService.loadJrxmlFile(inputFileName);
        String mySubReport = storageService.loadJrxmlFile(mySignatoriesSubReportFileName);

        // add logs of master report + subreport here
        log.info("{} loaded. Compiling report", jrxml);
        log.info("{} loaded. Compiling report", paiwiSignatoriesSubReport);

        params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", FileSystemUtil.rootLocation.toString() + "\\");

        // compile the master report together with the subreports
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml); // master report
        JasperReport compiledMySubReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(mySubReport); // sub-report

        // Save compiled report. Compiled report is loaded next time
        JRSaver.saveObject(jasperReport,
            storageService.loadJasperFile(inputFileName));

        JRSaver.saveObject(compiledMySubReport,
            storageService.loadJasperFile(mySignatoriesSubReportFileName));

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,
            dataSource);
        bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Encountered error when loading jasper file", e);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

This is what my master-report.jrxml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Autogen-contract" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="1008" columnWidth="540" leftMargin="36" rightMargin="36" topMargin="36" bottomMargin="36" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="4d5cd764-f78c-4d28-b2cc-4dadc9e584a1">

    <!-- Location of the compiled subreport. -->
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <!-- For data source of sub-reports -->
    <parameter name="mySignatoriesListSubReportDataSource" isForPrompting="true" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>

    <!-- This one works as of the master report -->
    <parameter name="farmName" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <!-- More details of the master report here.. -->

    <textField>
        <reportElement key="" x="135" y="120" width="270" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="2974af73-36ae-4781-a7b1-1b0a4a498c5c"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.lang.String.format("%s", $P{farmName})]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>

    <subreport>
        <reportElement x="1" y="520" width="537" height="20" uuid="fcf375d6-3935-42c9-bc81-1448e6f03ebf"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{mySignatoriesListSubReportDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "my-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>

    <!-- More details of the master report here.. -->

</jasperReport>
```

This is what my-subreport.jrxml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="paiwi-signatories-subreport" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="55585643-052e-4eee-9632-3c9b06dbec8f">
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="01eaeaca-361c-429f-9e71-e974b4f2beda">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>

    <!-- I have a name and address in the Signatory object I passed as a list of Data Source.. -->
    <!-- But this doesn't work.. or atleast it doesn't iterate anything -->
    <field name = "name" class = "java.lang.String"/>
    <field name = "address" class = "java.lang.String"/>

    <detail>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="20" uuid="5f357ce5-9928-4657-98f7-c7eace9b9e84"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="400" height="20" uuid="0390ae27-e46b-4bb4-87d0-83d59abfc22e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I can't access the fields in the sub-report, I don't even know if the parameter `farmSignatoriesListSubReportDataSource` in the master-report.xml actually goes through and enters the subreport as a valid data source.

Comment: 1) `I can't access the fields in the sub-report` - What does it mean?; 2) `I don't even know if the parameter ` - You can always check any parameter with help of textField (placed at Title band for example); 3) Are you really using `Dataset1` at subreport?; 4) Did you try to call supreport directly? Does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex, by question 1 I mean, I have name and address fields in the subreport.xml, but I can't use them even if I know I have name and address fields in my Signatory POJO object. I'm expecting I can access them since 1. I have a getter for that fields in the POJO object and 2. I injected them to the subreport since I put that List of Signatory as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource then as parameter before I compiled the master report. Then used it inside the <dataSourceExpression>. But since it doesn't work I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: You are passing an empty datasource to main report, so you must make sure that `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` (otherwise it will print nothing) and that the subreport is not in the detail band (since this will not exists, when empty dataource). Another solution would be to pass 1 empty record (`new JREmptyDataSource(1)`) to main report

Comment: You use several names for the parameter: in the parameters map you put it as `signatoriesListSubreportDataSource`, in the report it's called `mySignatoriesListSubReportDataSource`, and then in the description you talk about `farmSignatoriesListSubReportDataSource`.  I suggest double checking that the name in the parameters map is the same as the parameter name in the report.

Comment: @dada67 hi dada67! Thank you very much for this comment. It actually was the cause. I'm having a lot of confusion with regards to hashmaps in java going through jasperreports. it should be the same and will be received by the .jrxml after compilation. This finally shed some light. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If You want to pass the report parameter to subreport then use a subreportParameter tag like below.

```
<subreport>
        <reportElement x="-12" y="0" width="553" height="110" uuid="e012100d-4c24-468f-9d97-57cda4a0d64a"/>
                <subreportParameter name="cou_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{mySignatoriesListSubReportDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["my-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First you add a subreport to a main report. 
Define parameter in main report which you will set farmSignatoriesListSubReportDataSource at first.

Click the subreport you added open properties sub report tab and open edit parameters. There you will need to add a parameter , give a name to parameter of subreport , and as parameter expression select parameter from the main report which you've already set before. Then you will have your fields at subreport.